# Horizontal UIScrollView autolayout constraint localization

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints

I have multiple buttons separated by some 10px padding (leadingPadding), in case of English the items must start from left to right, and in case of Arabic from right to left and **centralized**.

This is the code used to draw the scrollView:

```
        var previousView: UIView = self.itemsScrollView!

        for i in 0..<self.items.count {

           let sectionButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)
           sectionButton.titleLabel.text = "i = " + i
           sectionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           self.itemsScrollView!.addSubview(sectionButton)

           // Left Constraint
          let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: sectionButton,
            attribute: .Leading,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: toView,
            attribute: (toView === self.itemsScrollView!) ? .Leading : .Trailing,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: leadingPadding);
          self.itemsScrollView! .addConstraint(leftConstraint)

          // Top Constraint
         let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: sectionButton,
            attribute: .Top,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: self.itemsScrollView!,
            attribute: .Top,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: self.itemPaddingTopBottom);
          self.itemsScrollView! .addConstraint(topConstraint)

          // Width Constraint
          let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: sectionButton,
            attribute: .Width,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: buttonWidth);
          self.itemsScrollView! .addConstraint(widthConstraint)


          // Height Constraint
          let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: sectionButton,
            attribute: .Height,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: itemHeight);
          self.itemsScrollView! .addConstraint(heightConstraint)

            previousView = sectionButton
        }

        // add Trailing constraint on scroll
        if (previousView !== self.itemsScrollView!) {
        let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: previousView,
            attribute: .Trailing,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: self.itemsScrollView!,
            attribute: .Trailing,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0);
        self.itemsScrollView! .addConstraint(leftConstraint)
        }
```

It works great when the language orientation is LTR.
[image]

And a weird behavior when the language orientation is RTL (They need to be centralized like the picture above)
[image]

I'm assuming this is something related to the Trailing constraint with the scrollView but I'm not sure. If yes, is there any way to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add multiple views directly in scrollview. Instead you should add a single container view ,horizontally centered in scrollview, which should include all the necessary subview. The width of the container view must be determined by its subviews, so the first item leading is aligned with container leading and the last item trailing is aligned with container trailing in LTR mode or first item trailing is aligned with container trailing and last item leading  is aligned with container leading in RTL mode